# Inaccurate results specific to environment

Tags: python, django

I have Python 3.4 running with Apache + Django framework.

My program reads from a text file (formatted) and searches for a few fields supplied to it. I am seeing inaccurate results for the search. For example, if I am searching for a number 300123, it would give me 5 results containing the match. If i look at the text file, there would be 10 results. So 5 are missing. This is just an example to show that results are inaccurate.

Tricky part is : If I restart apache (that also restarts django framework), my program starts to work fine. Then after some time, it would produce inaccurate results again (I am not sure how long it takes to go back to erroneous state.).

Also the same program works fine on my laptop which is running Python and Django (same version but without apache).

This leads me to believe that there some environmental issue with my setup. Any guidance how to troubleshoot it?

Here is my code:

```
  searched_data = data_from_file
  if cd['customer_id'] != None:
    cid = format(cd['customer_id'], ',')
    searched_data = [i for i in searched_data if i[3] == cid]
  if cd['reg'] != None:
    reg = format(cd['reg'], ',')
    searched_data = [i for i in searched_data if i[10] == reg]
  if cd['ip'] != '':
    searched_data = [i for i in searched_data if i[0] == cd['ip']]
  if cd['ver'] != '':
    searched_data = [i for i in searched_data if i[9] == cd['ver']]
  if cd['city'] != '':
    searched_data = [i for i in searched_data if i[11] == cd['city']]
  if cd['state'] != '':
    searched_data = [i for i in searched_data if i[12] == cd['state']]
  if cd['country'] != '':
    searched_data = [i for i in searched_data if i[13] == cd['country']]
  if cd['continent'] != '':
    searched_data = [i for i in searched_data if i[14] == cd['continent']]

  ### Code to display searched_data
  count = 1
  op_html = ''
  for a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17 in            searched_data:
    op_html += '<tr><th scope="row">'+str(count)+'</th><td>'+a0+'</td><td>'+a1+'</td><td>'+a2+'</td><td>'+a3+'</td><td>'+a5+'-'+a6+'-'+a7+'</td><td>'+a9+'</td><td>'+a10+'</td><td>'+a11+'</td><td>'+a12+'</td><td>'+a13+'</td><td>'+a14+'</td><td>'+a15+'</td><td>'+a16+'</td><td>'+a17+'</td>'
    count += 1
  context = {
               "op" : op_html
            }
  return render(request, 'result.html', context)
```

Apache config for WSGI:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myhost.lab.com python-path=/var/www/html/jrp/tools
WSGIProcessGroup myhost.lab.com
WSGIScriptAlias /j /var/www/html/jrp/tools/tools/wsgi.py
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/jrp’)
sys.path.append('/app01/html/jrp/.virtualenvs/dj/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tools.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: The answer might very much depend on the embedding of `django` into `apache`. Usually webservers will try to keep your script running infinitely rather than starting it from scratch upon each `http` access. This will make the script vulnerable against not closing or rewinding files properly, e.g in exceptional situations, which are difficult to detect in CLI or unittests. Maybe you want to search into that direction or add more detail about the embedding (probably `mod_wsgi` and it's configuration) of `django` into `apache` and also how your file is opened and closed...

Comment: Maybe you want to update the question with snipplets from the apache config and your file handling code?

Comment: I updated my question.